# Tips for making a fraction calculator code more optimized (faster and using less memory)

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Basicly, what I need for the program to do is to act a as simple fraction calculator (for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division) for the a single line of input, for example:
-input: `1/7 + 3/5`
-output: `26/35`

My initial code:

```
import sys

def euclid(numA, numB):
    while numB != 0:
        numRem = numA % numB
        numA = numB
        numB = numRem
    return numA

for wejscie in sys.stdin:
    wyjscie = wejscie.split(' ')
    a, b = [int(x) for x in wyjscie[0].split("/")]
    c, d = [int(x) for x in wyjscie[2].split("/")]
    if wyjscie[1] == '+':
        licz = a * d + b * c
        mian= b * d
        nwd = euclid(licz, mian)
        konA = licz/nwd
        konB = mian/nwd
        wynik = str(konA) + '/' + str(konB)
        print(wynik)
    elif wyjscie[1] == '-':
        licz= a * d - b * c
        mian= b * d
        nwd = euclid(licz, mian)
        konA = licz/nwd
        konB = mian/nwd
        wynik = str(konA) + '/' + str(konB)
        print(wynik)
    elif wyjscie[1] == '*':
        licz= a * c
        mian= b * d
        nwd = euclid(licz, mian)
        konA = licz/nwd
        konB = mian/nwd
        wynik = str(konA) + '/' + str(konB)
        print(wynik)
    else:
        licz= a * d
        mian= b * c
        nwd = euclid(licz, mian)
        konA = licz/nwd
        konB = mian/nwd
        wynik = str(konA) + '/' + str(konB)
        print(wynik)
```

Which I reduced to:

```
import sys

def euclid(numA, numB):
    while numB != 0:
        numRem = numA % numB
        numA = numB
        numB = numRem
    return numA

for wejscie in sys.stdin:
    wyjscie = wejscie.split(' ')
    a, b = [int(x) for x in wyjscie[0].split("/")]
    c, d = [int(x) for x in wyjscie[2].split("/")]
    if wyjscie[1] == '+':
        print("/".join([str((a * d + b * c)/euclid(a * d + b * c, b * d)),str((b * d)/euclid(a * d + b * c, b * d))]))
    elif wyjscie[1] == '-':
        print("/".join([str((a * d - b * c)/euclid(a * d - b * c, b * d)),str((b * d)/euclid(a * d - b * c, b * d))]))
    elif wyjscie[1] == '*':
        print("/".join([str((a * c)/euclid(a * c, b * d)),str((b * d)/euclid(a * c, b * d))]))
    else:
        print("/".join([str((a * d)/euclid(a * d, b * c)),str((b * c)/euclid(a * d, b * c))]))
```

Any advice on how to improve this futher is welcome.

Edit: one more thing that I forgot to mention - the code can not make use of any libraries apart from sys.

Comment: Yes, it is. Please note that I don't need a complete solution. What I'm looking for are general tips that might be applied in this case.

Comment: by calling `euclid(a*d,b*c)` multiple times you have probably made it slower than the version that stores the result in a variable

Comment: +1 for admitting that it's homework and not just looking for someone to do it for you. :)

Comment: On a side note, what is up with your variable names? Are those in a different language or are they just really cryptic abbreviates? `wyjscie`?

Comment: @musicfreak, perhaps it is Polish

Comment: @musicfreak: Yes, it's Polish. I just realised that would make my code more readable if the names were in English (duh!), this something I'll keep in mind for my future posts.

Comment: It's a Polish Notation calculator!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create a class containing `numerator` and `denominator` fields (both integers) and implementing `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, and `__div__` methods.  Then you can simply use ordinary math functions to combine the instances.

It might be overkill for your purposes, but the code will be a lot cleaner.

In fact, the class-based approach is exactly how the `fractions` module is implemented.  Normally I'd suggest examining the source code of the fractions module to see how it's written, but since this is for homework I'm not sure that would be allowed.  It might be worth checking out after the assignment is over, just to see how a full-blown fractional-number type is implemented.

Comment: +1 I think reading other people's well-written code is probably one of the best ways to learn how to write code well. You should definitely look at the source of the `fractions` module at some point as it is likely to be very well-written.

Comment: Great points there! I will definitely try to understand how it is done inside the fractions module. As Daniel said, it might be a bit of a overkill but that certainly not a waste. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the biggest improvement you could make would be to use Python (2.6)'s [`fractions`](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) library:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction(1,7) + fractions.Fraction("3/5")
Fraction(26, 35)
```

Comment: That would probably get the job done, if it was not for the fact (which a forgot to mention - sorry!) that I can not use any libraries apart from sys.

Answer (score 1):

You could factor out the code that reduces the fraction to lowest terms from the individual '+', '-', etc. That should make the code a little cleaner and more compact and readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) on the `euclid` function which may help speed up depending on the input data. However this will use more memory

You can also use a tuple assignment in `euclid`

```
def euclid(numA, numB):
    while numB != 0:
        numA, numB = numB, numA % numB
    return numA
```

map is faster here

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, wyjscie[0].split("/")+wyjscie[2].split("/"))
```

Comment: Euclid's algorithm takes O(log n) steps, so memoizing it will not help much.  Furthermore, many of the inputs may never be repeated so memoizing will just slowly leak memory the longer the program runs.

Comment: You could always try it memoized and non-memoized to see which one is faster. I suppose using the timeit module (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) would be acceptable, despite the rule against using libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring out `euclid` into a helper function is a good idea. I'd suggest trying to further break up your code into more helper functions.

One idea is to create four functions (add, subtract, multiply, divide) like this one:

```
def multiply(val1, val2):
    # Unpack the tuples.
    numerator1, denominator1 = val1
    numerator2, denoninator2 = val2

    # Figure out the resulting numerator and denominator here.

    # Return the result as a tuple.
    return numerator, denominator
```

Refactor your code to use the helper functions and I think your main code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can also optimize the euclid function . Instead of using Euclid's algorithm you can use [Binary GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

Two ways to implement the algorithm can be found [here](http://andreinc.net/2010/12/12/binary-gcd-steins-algorithm-in-c/), unfortunately the code is in C. Still I don't think is that hard if you translate it to python .